# How to use the struct inside a struct? invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, pointers, struct, rabbitmq

I am getting an panic when I want to use `Queue`. This is my struct:

```
type RabbitMQ struct {
    Connection    *amqp.Connection
    Channel       *amqp.Channel
    Queue         amqp.Queue // for consumer
    done          chan os.Signal
    notifyClose   chan *amqp.Error
    notifyConfirm chan *amqp.Confirmation
    IsConnected   bool
    alive         bool
    Done          chan os.Signal
    Err           chan error
    Wg            *sync.WaitGroup
}
```

This is the original `Queue` struct inside original library.

```
type Queue struct {
    Name      string // server confirmed or generated name
    Messages  int    // count of messages not awaiting acknowledgment
    Consumers int    // number of consumers receiving deliveries
}
```

Here in this function I am trying to use `r.Queue` by:

```
func (r *RabbitMQ) InitQueueForConsumer() {
    log.Println("inside initqueue")
    var err error
    r.Queue, err = r.Channel.QueueDeclare(
        "",    // name
        false, // durable
        false, // delete when unused
        true,  // exclusive
        false, // no-wait
        nil,   // arguments
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to declare a queue")
    }

    log.Println("inside initqueue")

    err = r.Channel.QueueBind(
        r.Queue.Name,
        "",
        "logs",
        false,
        nil,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to bind a queue")
    }
    log.Println("inside initqueue")
}

func (r *RabbitMQ) Consume() {
    msgs, err := r.Channel.Consume(
        r.Queue.Name,
        "",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to register a consumer")
    }

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case msg, ok := <-msgs:
                if !ok {
                    log.Printf("something wrong")
                    return
                }
                log.Printf("Received message: [%v]\n", msg)
            }
        }
    }()

    log.Printf("Waiting for logs")
    <-forever

}
```

I am calling this function like:

```
rmq := shared.RabbitMQ{}

go rmq.New()
for {
    go rmq.InitQueueForConsumer()
}
```

When I run I am getting the panic as follows:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x54 pc=0x11c27c6]

goroutine 22 [running]:
github.com/streadway/amqp.(*Channel).send(0x0, 0x1283c78, 0xc0000b0000, 0xc000071e28, 0x100e86a)
    /Users/barisertas/go/pkg/mod/github.com/streadway/amqp@v1.0.0/channel.go:157 +0x26
github.com/streadway/amqp.(*Channel).call(0x0, 0x1283c78, 0xc0000b0000, 0xc000071f40, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc000100050, 0x2)
    /Users/barisertas/go/pkg/mod/github.com/streadway/amqp@v1.0.0/channel.go:171 +0x5d
github.com/streadway/amqp.(*Channel).QueueDeclare(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/barisertas/go/pkg/mod/github.com/streadway/amqp@v1.0.0/channel.go:767 +0x150
github.com/bariis/rd/shared.(*RabbitMQ).InitQueueForConsumer(0xc000152000)
    /Users/barisertas/workspace/golang-exercises/rd/shared/rabbitmq.go:151 +0x90
created by main.main
    /Users/barisertas/workspace/golang-exercises/rd/receiver1/main.go:67 +0x76
exit status 2
```

And this what `queueDeclare` function returns from the original library:

```
func (ch *Channel) QueueDeclare(name string, durable, autoDelete, exclusive, noWait bool, args Table) (Queue, error) {
    if err := args.Validate(); err != nil {
        return Queue{}, err
    }

    req := &queueDeclare{
        Queue:      name,
        Passive:    false,
        Durable:    durable,
        AutoDelete: autoDelete,
        Exclusive:  exclusive,
        NoWait:     noWait,
        Arguments:  args,
    }
    res := &queueDeclareOk{}

    if err := ch.call(req, res); err != nil {
        return Queue{}, err
    }

    if req.wait() {
        return Queue{
            Name:      res.Queue,
            Messages:  int(res.MessageCount),
            Consumers: int(res.ConsumerCount),
        }, nil
    }

    return Queue{Name: name}, nil
}
```

I have tried every combination did with pointer, address etc. I tried to initialize it `New` function since it's called before `QueueDeclare` function I though It won't give panic but no solution. How can I do this properly?

Comment: I don't see code that created connection and channel from it.

Answer (score 2):

`rmq := shared.RabbitMQ{}` not initialising any fields in `RabbitMQ{}`. It assigns zero (default) values for all fields.

Zero (default) value of a pointer is nil. [tour here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)

So all pointers are nil inside `RabbitMQ{}`. So, when you going to access them in `InitQueueForConsumer()`, sure it will panic with `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

First Initialise atleast pointer fields before using them.

Zero (default) value of a channel is also nil. refer -[why-are-there-nil-channels-in-go](https://medium.com/justforfunc/why-are-there-nil-channels-in-go-9877cc0b2308).

But send to/receive from a nil channel not panics, but blocks forever. Closing a nil channel will panic with `runtime error: close of nil channel`